# What does the object mean?

Tags: word-meaning

The neoteric human being is now being cut off from the order of nature and establishes itself as the rationally reflecting and acting subject which is now posited against "the object" of its cognitive and practical activity.

What does "the object" in the sentence above mean?  Does it mean the goal of the activity?  Could you help me clarify it?  Thanks.

Comment: What's the title of the book? And can you please post a link, if possible.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.   It is a short article attached in PDF form.   The Self-criticism of Science: The contemporary philosophy of science & the problem of the scientific consciousness By Alexis Karpouzos